# How do you marry two object's holes in Freecad? 3D printing a drone

Tags: 3d-design, cad, freecad

I am 3D printing a drone and I need very good tolerances for the holes so the arms and motors align correctly.

I have two sets of 4 holes for two solid objects (Imported as STEP)

I want to align the two objects perfectly and possibly by using constraints. I was already able to create new Parts from the two .step files and draw sketches where the holes are.

How can I do this in Freecad?

[image]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, after about a week or so, then you might want to try [SE.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) as they have a number of CAD questions. However, don't cross-post, so first delete this question here and *then* post it on SE.Engineering.